# I want to connect Database on button action in a javafx scene

Tags: java, jdbc, javafx

I want to connect to database on button action method but I am having InvocationTargetException exception, I am new in java and got stuck here, Please look at the code I wrote. (sorry for this bad post I don't usually ask questions on the internet)

```
public class LoginController {
public static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world";
@FXML private static TextField txtfld;
@FXML private static PasswordField pwfld;
@FXML private Label connectionLabel;
@FXML private Button   btn1;

@FXML
public void btnOnAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
Connection conn= null;
Statement stmt = null;

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.println("Connecting to database");

    Connection connection  = DriverManager.getConnection(url,txtfld.getText(),pwfld.getText());

   System.out.println("Creating ");

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
};}
```

Here is FXML code.

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="background" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="345.0" prefWidth="330.0" styleClass="background" stylesheets="@dsadas.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.LoginController">
<children>
<TextField fx:id="txtfld" layoutX="91.0" layoutY="111.0" promptText="Username" AnchorPane.topAnchor="111.0" />
<PasswordField fx:id="pwfld" layoutX="91.0" layoutY="148.0" promptText="Password" />
<Button fx:id="btn1" layoutX="91.0" layoutY="195.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnOnAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" styleClass="btn1" text="Login" />
<Label fx:id="lbl2" layoutX="133.0" layoutY="57.0" text="Please login" textFill="#9382ff">
<font>
<Font size="11.0" />
</font>
</Label>
<Label layoutX="112.0" layoutY="22.0" text="Welcome" textFill="#5d8cf0">
<font>
<Font size="24.0" />
</font>
</Label>
<Label fx:id="connectionLabel" layoutX="148.0" layoutY="81.0" textFill="#e13434" />
</children>
<opaqueInsets>
<Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
</opaqueInsets>
</AnchorPane>
```

and here is exception

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1770)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8390)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$144/773961367.get(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/1660449789.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1765)
... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sample.LoginController.btnOnAction(LoginController.java:40)
... 60 more
```

Comment: Presumably the sql driver is not on your classpath.

Comment: It is already in the classpath, as i can run sample jdbc programs from it but thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: The stack trace explicitly states it is not in the classpath when you run this application though.

Comment: I dont know what happened, but when i removed it and added again it worked, thank you. but still I am having another exception. Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1770)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)

Comment: [edit] your question to include the full stack trace. That snippet does not even include the cause.

Comment: @James_D please look at the question now

Comment: @naqi Your question still doesn't have the full stack trace.  There must be a reason for `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`, please include it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Connector jar is not in application classpath.

Comment: thanks for your answer and database is connected but I am having another exception now please loo at the edited question.

Comment: edit your question to include full stack trace (with exception cause).

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sample.LoginController.btnOnAction(LoginController.java:40): this is the root cause of your problem now. Check what object is null when executing line 40.